# How to Implement MVVM in a .NET Core Console Application?

Tags: .net-core, design-patterns, entity-framework-core, cross-platform

I’d like to use .Net Core (Console App) and EF Core to create my business logic, a number crunching engine that loads financial data from a local database (MySQL or SQLite), process it, will store the results in the same database and show them to the user.

I want to be able to easily add in the future a GUI to manage the CRUD operations and simple commands.

How can I implement the MVVM pattern in a console application to be able to easily add a GUI in the future (Win7-10 and MacOs)?

Comment: "I want to be able to easily add in the future an UI"

I know this doesn't answer your question. But I think it's going to be a long long time before there is a cross platform GUI library that is on par with WPF/WinForms, if ever. So maybe rethink going through the trouble of building layers when it's very unlikely you will be using a GUI layer anytime soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Terminal.Gui](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs) Nuget package  includes:

> Reactive Example - A sample app that shows how to use `System.Reactive`
> and `ReactiveUI` with `Terminal.Gui`. The app uses the MVVM architecture
> that may seem familiar to folks coming from WPF, Xamarin Forms, UWP,
> Avalonia, or Windows Forms. In this app, we implement the data
> bindings using ReactiveUI WhenAnyValue syntax and [Pharmacist](https://github.com/reactiveui/pharmacist) — a tool
> that converts all events in a NuGet package into observable wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

Representing a view model on the command line sound like a natural mismatch. There are engines for drawing views using the terminal, however, in my opinion you should target the command line not with a mvvm pattern. MVC where the view is the console and the controller received the command line sounds like a better fit.

Comment: A MVVM view model needs a bidirectional bound view which require a full UI framework. Same is valid for MVP. MVC has two separate a unidirectional binding (outgoing view is text/HTML templating and incoming readline/HTTP controller requests).

Comment: Well, I mean that old-school DOS apps had ugly UIs, but they already had some complex ones. I don't know if there's some UI framework for console apps, but I don't see why it couldn't be one that update the UI when the model change and vice versa.

Comment: True. Just that databinding with mvvm was not topic then :)